# AS3: Remove and add to variable after a character

Tags: actionscript-3

I am pulling data from a php script that gives me the names of a person on facebook along with there ID in this format:

> Person Name:123456789

I would like to know if there is a away to split after the ":" and add the number (ID) to on array and the person name to another array.

Thanks for any help
Eli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var personArray:Array = [];
var idArray:Array = [];
var stringToSplit:String = "Person Name:123456789";
var splitArray:Array = stringToSplit.split(":");

personArray.push(splitArray[0]);
idArray.push(splitArray[1]);

trace(personArray); // outputs "Person Name"
trace(idArray); // outputs "123456789"
```

Comment: This only out puts "1" for both arrays when traced.

Comment: What would you need it to be? You mentioned you wanted the Id in one array and the name in another array. Will you have multiple user pairs?

Comment: i need it to be "Person Name" in one array, and 123456789 in another array. but this only seems to but the number 1 in both the arrays.

Comment: Calling trace(personArray) or trace(idArray) outputs correctly with this code. What are you tracing?